# angular 4 two routes that ends with the same path but lead to different modules

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have angular 4 project with the following hierarchy

- app

  - fUsers

    - home

      - home.component.ts
      - home.module.ts
      - home.routes.ts
    - fUsers.module.ts
    - fUsers.routes.ts
  - lUsers

    - dashboard

      - dashboard.component.ts
      - dashboard.module.ts
      - dashboard.routes.ts
    - lUsers.module.ts
    - lUsers.routes.ts
  - app.component.ts
  - app.module.ts
  - app.routes.ts

in each routes.ts file I have the following routes settings:

```
const appRoutes:Routes=[
                 {
                      path: "fUsers",
                      loadChildren: "./fUsers/fUsers.module#FUsersModule",
                    },
                    {
                      path: "lUsers",
                      loadChildren: "./lUsers/lUsers.module#LUsersModule",
                    }
            ]

   const fUsersRoutes:Routes=[    {
                  path: "home",
                  loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule",
                }
            ]


            const lUsersRoutes: Routes =[
                {
                  path: "home",
                  loadChildren: "./dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule",
                }
            ]


            const homeRoutes:Routes = [    
            {
                  path: "",
                  component: HomeComponent
                }
            ]

  const dashboardRoutes: Routes=[
                {
                  path: "",
                  component: DashboardComponent
                }
            ]
```

when I navigate to **/fUsers/home** everything works fine but when I navigate to **/lUsers/home** the page cannot found

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it I forgot to change the folder name as well, under lUsers I changed the dashboard folder to home...